# Swift. Как сделать при прокрутке ScrollView сначала прокрутить его на весь экран, а только потом прокручивать содержимое?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Заметил в некоторых приложениях интересное поведение скрола. Например в приложении Viber в меню "Ещё" в верхней части имеется какой-то header view, ниже расположена, как мне кажется, таблица uitableview. При прокрутке вниз сначала скрывается верхний header и таблица выравнивается на весь экран и только затем в ней прокручивается контент:
[image: Экран прокручен вверх]

[image: При начале прокрутке скрывается верхний header]

[image: Таблица стала на весь экран и верхний header превратился во что-то похожее на navigation bar]

Причем этот скрол происходит плавно вместе с прокруткой, даже если немного свайпнуть пальцем и отпустить его, скрол продолжит с такой же инерцией двигаться и скрывать плавно верхний header view и после прокручивать саму таблицу. Как добиться такого же эффекта?

Я пробовал сделать аналогично с помощью `scrollViewDidScroll`, но получилось сделать только следующее:
[image: Прокрутка]

При начале прокрутке прокручивается сама таблица и вместе с этим ещё и скрывается header view, получается увеличенная скорость прокрутки. Может можно как-то сделать чтобы вначале прокрутка в таблице шла, но контент в ней фактически оставался на одном месте.

Мой код следующий:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if y <= headerViewHeight && y >= 0 {
        tableViewTopAnchor.constant = -y
    } else if tableViewTopAnchor.constant != -headerViewHeight && y > headerViewHeight {
        tableViewTopAnchor.constant = -headerViewHeight
    }
}

let headerViewHeight: CGFloat = 150
```

Storyboard:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал для остановки прокрутки контента в таблице в `scrollViewDidScroll` использовать `scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0`, но тогда прокрутка вообще перестаёт работать(

Аналогичное поведение так же можно увидеть в приложении Сбербанк Онлайн на главной странице(и на некоторых других).
Может кто-то где-то видел уже такое решение или знает как так сделать?